# How to controll blurness of UIBlurEffect

Tags: ios, effects

Is there a way to set how blurry/sharp the view is going to be ? I spent a lot of time trying to find, with no success. Adjusting alpha is not flexible enough. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the problem by using this small but pretty good library. One can customize blur radius as much as one wishes.
https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. Use another library for blurring that allows you to control the level of blur such as [iOS-blur](https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur) or [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView).

Comment: Or Apple's `UIImage+ImageEffects` category found in `iOS_UIImageEffects` in the [WWDC 2013 sample code](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013). Or use `CIGaussianBlur` Core Image filter.